# How can I float upwards with the boots of cheapness?

Tags: keyboard, you-found-the-grappling-hook

In "You Found The Grappling Hook" (YFTGH), I am stuck at the point shown in the picture: there is a gap between the platform and the ladder. When I float with the boots of cheapness, I cannot manage to reach at least the bottom of the ladder.

However, [a guy manages to float upwards](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9n2hWKE_TQ#t=3m40s). Which controls are to be used?

[image: The bottleneck]

Comment: According to the comments, you press Z to do so. This is only a comment though, because I have no experience playing this game, so I don't really know.

Comment: Pressing 'Z' helps float a bit, but I cannot move upwards. Or maybe you are right, but then it means I am not able to press the button fast enough. :'(

Comment: I found [this](http://www.indiefaqs.com/index.php/You_Found_the_Grappling_Hook) which supports the idea of pressing Z to float using the hover boots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Start from the left edge.
2. Run towards the right edge and try to jump on the very last second possible.
3. When you start to vertically slow down in air smash the Z button like mad.
4. If you can't seem to do this, you might want to create a macro that does this for you.

   Perhaps do this [Hourglass](http://code.google.com/p/hourglass-win32/) style, [credits for finding this go to badp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24240/is-there-a-macro-player-recorder-for-games).